# Highstock - display number of week

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I show the week number for the date in Highstock (**not Highcharts**!)?

My SQL looks like this

```
select unix_timestamp(date)*1000 week
(....)
group by yearweek(date,3)
```

My JS

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('json_chart.php', function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 2
            },

            title : {
                text : 'Wyniki'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%e'
                }
            },
            yAxis: [{
                offset: 40,
                title: {
                    text: 'Ilośc'
                },
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Efek'
                },
                opposite: true,
            }],

            series : [{
                name : 'Ode',
                data : data.ode,
                type : 'column',
                yAxis: 0
            },{
                name : 'Sku',
                data : data.sku,
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius : 3
                },
                yAxis: 1,
                shadow : true
            },{
                name : 'TK',
                data : data.tpk,
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius : 3
                },
                yAxis: 0,
                shadow : true
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

But I want to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add it using `dateFormats`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/EkAnm/

```
Highcharts.dateFormats = {
    W: function (timestamp) {
        var date = new Date(timestamp),
            day = date.getUTCDay() == 0 ? 7 : date.getUTCDay(),
            dayNumber;
        date.setDate(date.getUTCDate() + 4 - day);
        dayNumber = Math.floor((date.getTime() - new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1, -6)) / 86400000);
        return 1 + Math.floor(dayNumber / 7);

    }
}
```

Then use it in or `format` or `dateFormat()`:

```
xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 36e5, // one week
        labels: {
            format: '{value:Week %W/%Y}'
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep weeks and years consistent, I tend to use ISO-8601 standard when dealing with week numbering.

With Pawel answer and the js code from [this blog](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/33796/14863/calculate-iso-8601-week-and-year-in-javascript.html), I set up the following solution.

```
Highcharts.dateFormats = {
        V: function (timestamp) {    
            var target  = new Date(timestamp);  
            var dayNr   = (target.getDay() + 6) % 7;  
            target.setDate(target.getDate() - dayNr + 3);  
            var firstThursday = target.valueOf();  
            target.setMonth(0, 1);  
            if (target.getDay() != 4) {  
                target.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4 - target.getDay()) + 7) % 7);  
            }  
            return 1 + Math.ceil((firstThursday - target) / 604800000); // 604800000 = 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000  
        }  ,
        G: function(timestamp) {
            var target  = new Date(timestamp);  
            target.setDate(target.getDate() - ((target.getDay() + 6) % 7) + 3);  
            return target.getFullYear();  
        }
};
```

%V and %G respects the [strftime format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) used in highstock.

Comment: I'm getting week 53 for a timestamp that is on 4th Jan 2016 with this code... But natee's code below here gives week 1.

Comment: european and us weeknumbers differ. ISO8601 needs to have the majority of the days in the new year in order to get week 1. So 4 jan 2016 is in week 53 of 2015.

Answer (score 1):

For @Paweł Fus  's answer, I find out that when the date is 2012/1/1 witch was Sunday,the result is wrong, so I have changed the answer to :

```
W: function (timestamp) {
    var date = new Date(timestamp);
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1); 
    var day = firstDay.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : firstDay.getDay();
    var days = Math.floor((date.getTime() - firstDay)/86400000) + day; // day numbers from the first Monday of the year to current date
    return Math.ceil(days/7);
},
```