# Need to find the week number in a calendar quarter of a given date with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to find the week # within a calendar quarter using javascript (like Quarter 1, week 1) of a given date (like 10/2/18).  The output needs to be a number, which will represent the week # of the quarter that day falls on.  For example, if I have a date of 1/1/18, I want to have a return value of "1" - which represents week 1. The purpose is to compare data for one quarter with another in a column chart where the x-axis points are weeks.  So for example, I'd like to  compare data in week 1 in Q1 with week 1 in Q2. I'm using Highcharts.js to generate the chart.

[Example quarterly comparison chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWgJ0.png)

The following discussion talks about how to return the number of the week.  I'm trying to go one step further and get week # in the quarter (not week # in the year):

[Highstock - display number of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850809/highstock-display-number-of-week)

```js
function QW: (timestamp) {
  var date = new Date(timestamp);
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  var day = firstDay.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : firstDay.getDay();
  var days = Math.floor((date.getTime() - firstDay) / 86400000) + day; // day numbers from the first Monday of the year to current date
  var week = Math.ceil(days / 7);
  var quarterweek = 0;
  //trying to get the quarter ranges here (assuming 13 week quarters - not taking into account leap year)...
  //*should* return a number between 1 - 13.
  if (week > 13 && week <= 26) { //q2
    quarterweek = Math.floor(week / 2);
  } else if (week > 26 && week <= 40) { //q3
    quarterweek = Math.floor(week / 3);
  } else if (week > 40 && week <= 52) { //q4
    quarterweek = Math.floor(week / 4);
  } else {
    quarterweek = week;
  }

  return quarterweek;
}
```

However, it's not working, and doesn't take into account leap year scenarios where quarters may be longer the 13 weeks.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use moment.js for operations like this

Comment: In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI5af.png

Comment: Doesn't `let weekOfQuarter = (weekOfYear % 13) + 1` do the trick?

Comment: How do you define a quarter? Sometimes January is Q1, sometimes it's Q3. Are you using ISO week numbering (i.e. first week of year is the one with the first Thursday of the year, 1 Jan 2016 was in the last week of 2015)? Some years have 52 weeks, some 53. Where does the spare week go? Are your weeks Sun to Sat or Mon to Sun (or something else)?

Comment: I tried using both regular and ISO weeks.  The ISO week seems to work better after testing (which is not reflected in the example above).  Jan is Q1, but we have the concept of custom fiscal quarters, which you can determine by setting the month of Q1.  Our weeks are Sun to Sat.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all - I was able to get the weeks of a quarter by using the modulus operator that Sani Sing Huttunen suggested above.  I also had some luck with using momentjs - thank you charlieftl!